# how to find all "unlabled" gmail messages through IMAP?

Tags: email, gmail, imap, cloud-storage, gmail-imap

Bulk deleting non-labeled e-mails through the `gmail` web interface is [less than perfect](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/101127/whats-the-workflow-to-bulk-delete-e-mails-from-within-gmail).

Might there be some way to search for e-mails which are not in a specific folder?  Gmail is rather unique in that everything is stored, sometimes multiple times.  So that if an e-mail is stored *only* in all-mail then it could be marked for deletion.  Theoretically.

> In theory there is no difference between theory and practice; in
>   practice there is.

-[not](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Yogi_Berra) yogi berra

Comment: You already know webapps.stackexchange.com; why don't you ask there?

Comment: Thunderbird might give you a more granular search option, rather than using the web interface.

Comment: @n.st because I was looking for a non-web base solution.